# Tiny MCE добавляет к шаблону пкустые теги <p>

Tags: tinymce

Как выключить это? Надо чтобы Tiny MCE не добавлял свои теги.

Answer (score 0):

надо добавить св-во `forced_root_block: false` в параметры инициализации

Answer (score 0):

В версии 6 forced_root_block: false это свойство не работает, плагин добавляет теги

ко всем элементам, которые этого требуют, автоматически. К элементам , и прочим блочным тег

не добавляется

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/729560)